# Call function from views and record user activity - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with some users, and to discover the problem I want to record things, in views and controller.

I use:

Controller.php

```
public function records($user_id, $event_id, $action){

    $record = new Record();
    $record->user_id = $user_id;
    $record->event_id = $event_id;
    $record->action = $action;
    $record->save();
}
```

What I use in my controllers

```
$this->records(0, 0,'user in this step');
```

What I'm trying in views.blade.php

```
{{\App\Http\Controllers\Controller::records(0, 0,'ajax success')}}
```

> This returns the error: Non static method

```
{{\App\Http\Controllers\Controller->records(0, 0,'ajax success')}}
```

> This returns the error: "->" unexpected operator

So How can I call the function? Probably it's easy but I'm new with Laravel.

Thanks

Comment: `{{\App\Http\Controllers\Controller->records(0, 0,'ajax success')}}`
Doesn't seem ideal since it runs at page load.
Try to send it via ajax when something happens

Comment: this is just for the ajax and some other functions that are not executed on load but on user actions. But still giving errors "->" unexpected operator

Comment: But having that in the file, means that is called once the page is loaded, even if you get it to work. answer below will make it work indeed but will be run once page is loaded.
I recomend adding a route, and sending a ajax request to it whenever required

Comment: @SérgioReis oh, you're right! what a pitty! I'll try the ajax thing. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
You can call function from view like below.

@php

$controllerObj = new \App\Http\Controllers\Controller();
$controllerObj->records(0, 0,'ajax success');

@endphp
```

Comment: thank you very much, so to put several I can define at the beginning of the file and the  do the record on each event. nothing shorter can be made right?

Comment: You can use this code where you want to need. not get your comment concern.

Comment: what i want to say.. i'm not clear on what's your requirement. you can use done your work this way. if you want more help then put more descrition and code exmple..

Comment: It would be better to create a route and refer to your controller from this route. Then call this route from within your view. This is the way you build (ajax-) requests in Laravel.